# How to show selected JSON data in the pickerview?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uipickerview

I have a 2 textviews and 2 pickerviews. I want the user to select the city and district of that city. When I select the city I want to list the districts of that city in the pickerview. I don't use city model.

When the city is selected, I want the districts of that city to appear in pickerview. How to do this?

My JSON data:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
          "il_adi": "Adana",          -- cityNames
      "plaka_kodu": " 01",
      "alan_kodu": "0322",
      "nufus": "2.274.106",
      "bolge": "Akdeniz",
      "yuzolcumu": "13.844",
      "nufus_artisi": "4,7%",
      "erkek_nufus_yuzde": "49.15%",
      "erkek_nufus": "1.106.811",
      "kadin_nufus_yuzde": "50.15%",
      "kadin_nufus": "1.113.314",
      "nufus_yuzdesi_genel": "2,71%",
      "ilceler": [                    --         districts 
        {
          "plaka_kodu": "1",
          "ilce_kodu": "1757",
          "il_adi": "ADANA",
          "ilce_adi": "ALADAĞ",       --- district name
          "nufus": "15.855",
          "erkek_nufus": "8.194",
          "kadin_nufus": "7.661"
        }
```

My data function:

```swift
func ilce(){
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yusif", ofType: "json") else {return}
   
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do{
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        
        selectedCity = try JSONDecoder().decode(cityOfModel.self, from: jsonData)
        
        if let selectedCity = selectedCity{
            print(selectedCity)
        }
    } catch{
        print("hataaaaa")
    }
}
```

My pickerview code:

```swift
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    switch pickerView.tag {
    case 1:
        return selectedCity!.data.count
        
        
    case 2:
        return ???? 
        
    default :
        return 0
    }
   

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch pickerView.tag {
        case 1:
            return selectedCity!.data[row].ilAdi
        case 2:
            return selectedCity!.data[row].ilceler[row].ilceAdi
        default:
            return "HATA"
    }
}
```

My model:

```swift
struct cityOfModel: Codable {
    let data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
    let ilAdi, plakaKodu, alanKodu, nufus: String
    let bolge: Bolge
    let yuzolcumu, nufusArtisi, erkekNufusYuzde, erkekNufus: String
    let kadinNufusYuzde, kadinNufus, nufusYuzdesiGenel: String
    let ilceler: [Ilceler]
    let kisaBilgi: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ilAdi = "il_adi"
        case plakaKodu = "plaka_kodu"
        case alanKodu = "alan_kodu"
        case nufus, bolge, yuzolcumu
        case nufusArtisi = "nufus_artisi"
        case erkekNufusYuzde = "erkek_nufus_yuzde"
        case erkekNufus = "erkek_nufus"
        case kadinNufusYuzde = "kadin_nufus_yuzde"
        case kadinNufus = "kadin_nufus"
        case nufusYuzdesiGenel = "nufus_yuzdesi_genel"
        case ilceler
        case kisaBilgi = "kisa_bilgi"
    }
}

enum Bolge: String, Codable {
    case akdeniz = "Akdeniz"
    case bolgeDoğuAnadolu = "Doğu Anadolu "
    case doğuAnadolu = "Doğu Anadolu"
    case ege = "Ege"
    case güneydoğuAnadolu = "Güneydoğu Anadolu"
    case i̇çAnadolu = "İç Anadolu"
    case karadeniz = "Karadeniz"
    case marmara = "Marmara"
}

// MARK: - Ilceler
struct Ilceler: Codable {
    let plakaKodu, ilceKodu, ilAdi, ilceAdi: String
    let nufus, erkekNufus, kadinNufus: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case plakaKodu = "plaka_kodu"
        case ilceKodu = "ilce_kodu"
        case ilAdi = "il_adi"
        case ilceAdi = "ilce_adi"
        case nufus
        case erkekNufus = "erkek_nufus"
        case kadinNufus = "kadin_nufus"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when "ilce" function does call? and the first picker view tag(city pickerview) is 1? and also do reload picker view after call "ilce" function?

Comment: First picker view tag is city name. When the city is selected, the districts of the city will be displayed in the 2nd pickerview but when we select any city, all districts are displayed. I do not want it to be like this.

Comment: Basically what you need to do is that when something is selected in the first picker you need to store that value or index in a property and then use that property when working with the second picker. Like this code snippet where you incorrectly use the `row` value in two places, `selectedCity!.data[row].ilceler[row].ilceAdi`. Instead you should use the saved property I mentioned above for the first occurrence

Comment: thanks for answer but don't we use row for this? I don't understand ?

Comment: You only use row for the current picker

Comment: Ok, how to do this ? can you give an example?

Comment: ok I solve this, I use this code;


let sCty = pickerVier.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)